# Angularjs Partial View vs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Our SPA has 2 distinctive top level views. To compare it is like windows file explorer showing tree view on one side and content details on other side. For these top level views, we are considering to have 2 partial views. Other alternative is to pack these views as directives. Our initial thoughts are going toward partial views, because these are quite larger blocks of functionalties and each view can have multiple controllers. Any experience/thoughts on similar lines would help us decide. Just a note we communicate between these views using eventing mechanism.

We do not intend to reuses these views. Specifically, are there any issues going partial views? Like performance, maintainability, etc.

Comment: Don't use directives. Their purpose is not for what you describe

Comment: Happy to be proven wrong, but I think unless you're using ui-router, you can only have a single view in your page.  That might make you decide to use a directive for at least one of your "views".

Comment: @Martin that is not correct. You still can use ngInclude and it still would be better than a Directive

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem here, so sorry if I say something wrong (also sorry for my english).
What you need are 2 views; if 'inside' those views you use a directive or not, it's another thing.
The only thing I'm pretty sure is that those 2 views need to have they're own `scope`.

To me it seems a lot like a 'navigation menu' vs. 'view' kind of problem (only that the navigation part is gonna be some sort of tree-view), so the solution should be similar:

- the 'normal' `ngView` (your 'details' side);
- a `div` with it's own controller (and it's own scope).

Something like:

```
<nav ng-controller="treeViewController()">
    <!-- here we use a directive, for example -->
    <tree-view ng-model="tree"></tree-view>
</nav>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Then the best way to make them communicate is probably a custom service.

In case I misunderstood your problem, sorry in advance.